# Not Able to Register a Third Party DLL Using regsvr32

Tags: c#, regsvr32

I have been trying to register a third party dll file using the `regsvr32` command, but it keeps giving me the error `the dll doesn't have a entry point, dll could not be registered`. Is it possible to register this dll and use it as a COM component in .NET ? I am running command prompt with admin privileges.

What if I want to use that dll as a COM component in c#.NET? Is there any way to use that dll as COM Component? When I tried to use it as COM component, the dll file, its methods, interfaces are visible in .NET. But when I tried to use any of that interface it gives me error as `Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {C4CC4F47-2AF6-41FA-A43D-01E8B3050D3F} failed due to the following error: 80040154.`.

Comment: are you running the command with administrator credentials?

Comment: yes, i have admin privileges.

Comment: When regsvr32 fails like that, it is telling you that it is not a COM server.  When you actually have a CLSID guid then it is probably a [ComVisible] .NET assembly.  In which case you never use COM, you use the classes directly.  Contact the vendor for support.

Comment: Make sure you are running 32-bit.

Comment: @leppie : Yep. Running on 32-bit